# How can i designate a script to be run at startup that floats a certain input method?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, scripts, keyboard, xinput

so my thinkpad has been having keyboard issues so i use an external keyboard. The issue im having, however, is that plugging in the keyboard still allows the base keyboard to type stuff and that means my '1' key is in a constant state of being pressed. I found a way to solve this by running

```
sudo xinput list
```

Finding "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" and its ID and then running

```
sudo xinput float <id>
```

What code would i need to run xinput list and find a specific string the run xinput float ? The ID is usually 14 but sometimes it changes so i can't just run `sudo xinput float 14` all the time. Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

While the device ID might change... the device name will, in most cases, remain the same. Therefore, you can use the device name in the query to get its specific ID like so:

```
xinput list --id-only "Virtual core XTEST keyboard"
```

Replace `Virtual core XTEST keyboard` with the name of your specific keyboard you get from `xinput list`

You can use it with `xinput float` like so:

```
xinput float "$(xinput list --id-only 'Virtual core XTEST keyboard')"
```

Comment: omg thank you so much!! i'll test it out in the morning